# Efficient algorithm perl or python

Tags: python, algorithm, perl

Interviewer asked a question in an interview to write fast & efficient algorithm for below function,

Problem: Write a function to parse a given string for below given rules & produce final parsed string as output

write a function which will accepts string as input, string length will be in between [0..2000000000]

> string should be made from only **'A','B' & 'C' characters** like 'AAA' ,'ABCABC','AAAABBBBABAAACCCA'

### Transformation Rules:

**1) 'AB' -> 'AA' 

2) 'AC' -> 'AA' 

3) 'AA' -> 'A' 

4) 'CC' -> 'C' 

5) 'BC' -> 'BB' 

6) 'BB' -> 'B'**

**Apply all above 6 rules randomly on given string each at a time and make final transformed string as output**

For example input to Function is: 'ABCAAB' string

ABCAAB -> AACAAB [AB = AA] 
AACAAB -> ACAAB  [AA = A] 
ACAAB -> AAAAB   [AC = AA] 
AAAAB -> AAAB [AA = A] 
AAAB -> AAB [AA = A] 
AAB -> AB [AA = A] 
AB -> AA [AB = AA] 
AA -> A [AA = A]

Final result: **'A'**

Because we can not apply any more rules to the string now.

My Answer was like (pseudocode):

```
sub myFunc {
my $str = @_;
flag = 1
while(flag ==1) {
    if ($str =~ /AB/){
    $str =~ s/AB/AA/;
    next;
    }
    elsif($str =~ /AC/){
    $str =~ s/AC/AA/;
    next;
    }
    elsif($str =~ /AA/){
    $str =~ s/AA/A/;
    next;
    }
    elsif($str =~ /CC/){ 
    $str =~ s/CC/C/;
    next;
    }
    elsif($str =~ /BC/){ 
    $str =~ s/BC/BB/;
    next;
    }
    elsif($str =~ /BB/){ 
    $str =~ s/BB/B/;
    next;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = 0
    }
} //while
 return $str;
} //func
```

Can someone suggest better algorithm & approach for above problem ?

Comment: ... and what's your question/problem?

Comment: @Karoly: please suggest optimized solution/algorithem for above problem.

Comment: How does the above code "apply all 7 rules randomly"? Also (if it doesn't have to be random) wouldn't it be more efficient to use if's instead if else's (as you wouldn't need the while loop)?

Comment: @Rob: I wrote loop because they told me to apply one rule at a time, so we can't use global identifier 'g' in pattern matching. :(

Comment: There is a trick I guess: the order of the substitutions does not matter.

Comment: If the code completely works, this would be better on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why did you add both Perl and Python to the tags?

Comment: @Izkata : Because I know both Perl & Python both :)

Answer (score 15):

Rules 1 to 3 will discard any character following an A.
Rules 5 and 6 will discard any B and C following a B.
Rule 4 will discard any C following a C. The order of the substitutions does not matter.

So after processing the string will be one of C, CB, CA, CBA, B, BA, A.

A single scan of the string will suffice. If you see a C, keep it and skip the next C's; then if you see a B, keep it and skip the next B's; then if you see an A keep it and stop.

The given example ABCAAB immediately yields A.

Solutions with explicit application of the rules and multiple passes are unacceptable as their behavior can be `O(N²)` or even `O(N³)`, while `N=2000000000`.

Comment: You are welcome. Seeing the length up to 2000000000 hinted me that there was a trick.

Comment: Do you have a good idea how to actually implement it? In my answer I use `find()`, as it's very fast. But I need two scans. And I can't think of a faster way that scans just once.

Comment: Three if tests and three while loops. Except for pathological cases, speed is not an issue here, parsing stops at the first A.

Answer (score 8):

You can repeat substitution while it matches transformation rules,

```
my %h = (
  'AB' => 'AA',
  'AC' => 'AA', 
  'AA' => 'A', 
  'CC' => 'C', 
  'BC' => 'BB', 
  'BB' => 'B', 
);
my $s = 'ABCAAB';

1 while $s =~ s/(AB|AC|AA|CC|BC|BB)/$h{$1}/; # also without /g switch
print $s;
```

output

```
A
```

Comment: @n33rma there is no /g switch.

Comment: Let me try , Thank you so much for your solution

Comment: Sorry I can't vote your answer , it says "you need 15 reputation to vote"

Comment: @n33rma: Now you can vote. You have enough reputation to upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a python solution:

```
In [34]: import ranodm
In [35]: rules = {"AB":"AA",'AC':'AA','AA':'A','CC':'C','BC':'BB','BB':'B'}

In [36]: keys = rules.keys()

In [37]: keys
Out[37]: ['AA', 'AC', 'AB', 'BB', 'BC', 'CC']

In [38]: mystr = 'ABCAAB' 

In [42]: while len(mystr)>=2:
    r = random.choice(keys) #choose one rule randomly 
    mystr = mystr.replace(r,rules[r])
   ....:   

In [43]: mystr
Out[43]: 'A'
```

Comment: Yes I tried but it says "you need 15 reputation to vote" Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

[Yves Daoust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502806/1672429) is right, makes no sense to simulate it. Seems like a trick question and that you were supposed to realize that and understand the behavior and implement it directly.

Yves' method works, but here's an actual implementation of a similar one:

```
def transform(string):
    a = string.find('A') + 1
    b = string.find('B', 0, a or len(string)) + 1
    return 'C' * string.startswith('C') + 'B' * (b>0) + 'A' * (a>0)
```

I search for the first 'A', then search for a 'B' left of it (or in the whole string, if there was no 'A'). That tells me whether 'B' and 'A' belong into the output. For 'C' I just need to check the start of the string. While I potentially scan the whole string twice rather than just once like Yves suggests, using the `find` function makes pretty it fast, about a 100 times faster than just looping over the string "by hand" and just looking for an 'A' (which is only at the end of my teststring):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> s = 'C' * 100000000 + 'BA'

>>> timeit(lambda: transform(s), number=1)
0.10583857561359977

>>> timeit(lambda: next(x for x in s if x == 'A'), number=1)
10.957446603791382
```

You could do it with just one scan by using `lstrip('C')` to find the first non-'C' character, and that's faster than doing it by hand, but that uses extra memory and is still much slower than `find`:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: s.lstrip('C'), number=1)
2.411250071361735
```

Regular expressions could probably also do it, but even just scanning my teststring once just looking for 'A' takes longer than my whole `transform`:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: re.search('A', s), number=1)
0.13403880409939006
```